# can not print statement in bill program

Tags: java

the question is :-

> Design a billing system for Majan electricity. Majan electricity has two types of customers: domestic and business. Different rates are applied to domestic connections and to business.
>
> Identify required data and implement the required operations.
>   The program should display the following menu:
>       Welcome to Majan electricity Billing
>   1.  Domestic Customer
>   2.  Business Customer
>   Enter your choice:
>       If the choice is 1, read necessary information, find bill, print billing details.
>       If the choice is 2, read necessary information, find bill, print billing details.

I solved as following -:

```
    public void Domestic( String Dname, String Did,int current , int last , int cost )
    {
        int Dactual= current - last;

        if(Dactual<=500)
                {

            cost = (int) (0.15 * Dactual);

                 System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
                }
                           else if(Dactual>501 && Dactual<1000)
                                   {
                                       cost = (int) (0.20 * Dactual);
                                   System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
                                   }


                else
{
 cost = (int) (0.25 * Dactual);
System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
}

    }

    public void Business(String Bid, String Bname, int Bcurrent , int Blast ,  int cost)
    {
          int Bactual= Bcurrent - Blast;

                if(Bactual<=600)
                {
              cost = (int) (0.15 * Bactual);

                  System.out.println("The actual reading is "+Bactual);
                 System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
                }
                           else if(Bactual>601 && Bactual<1000)
                                   {
                                       cost = (int) (0.20 * Bactual);
             System.out.println("The actual reading is "+Bactual);
                                       System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
                                   }


                else
{
 cost = (int) (0.35 * Bactual);
 System.out.println("The actual reading is "+Bactual);
 System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
}
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
               Majan obj = new Majan() ;
         System.out.println("Welcome to Majan Electricity Billing");
         System.out.println("1. Domestic Customer  ");
         System.out.println("2. Business Customer ");
         System.out.println("Select your choice");
         int ch = sc.nextInt();
          switch(ch)
            {
                case 1 :
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String Dname= sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your Account No.");
        String Did= sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your current month reading");
         int current= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your previous month reading ");
                   int Dlast= sc.nextInt();
                    obj.Domestic(Dname, Did, current, Dlast, Dlast);
                    break;
                case 2 :
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String Bname= sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your Account No. ");
        String Bid= sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your current month reading");
         int Bcurrent= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your previous month reading ");
                   int Blast= sc.nextInt();
                      obj.Business(Bid, Bname, Bcurrent, Blast, Blast);
                    break;
                      default :
                          System.out.println("Wrong choice ! ");

}

}
}
```

the problem is -:

I cant see the final detail"name,account num ,etc" when I calculate ..
and --- this statement

```
System.out.println("The actual reading is "+Bactual);
```

dosnt appear!

The output is :-

```
 Welcome to Majan Electricity Billing
    1. Domestic Customer  
    2. Business Customer 
    Select your choice
1
Enter your name
juju
Enter your Account No.
345
Enter your current month reading
300
Enter your previous month reading 
100
The cost is 30**
```

Thank u

Comment: FYI: Variables shouldn't start with an upper case letter

Comment: Well, you print those information only in the business case, but in your example you use the domestic case... also, _please_ fix your indentation!

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: giving your problem statement..? working for which company.?

Comment: This sentence is also not clear: "I cant see the final detail "name,account num ,etc" when I calculate" You have no code where this information is being printed to system.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose 1 (Domestic Customer), you call the `Domestic` method, which in fact, does not executes `System.out.println("The actual reading is "+Bactual);`. That line of code is executed only by the `Bussiness` method of your class (option 2).

Answer (score 0):

Buddy you are passing the value 1 i.e. `Domestic` and your domestic function is

```
public void Domestic( String Dname, String Did,int current , int last , int cost )
{
    int Dactual= current - last;
    if(Dactual<=500)
    {
        cost = (int) (0.15 * Dactual);
        System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
    }
    else if(Dactual>501 && Dactual<1000)
    {
        cost = (int) (0.20 * Dactual);
        System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
    }
    else
    {
        cost = (int) (0.25 * Dactual);
        System.out.println("The cost is "+cost );
    }
}
```

where you are not having any line which is

```
System.out.println("The actual reading is "+Bactual);
```

That's why you do not get `The actual reading is` in the output.

Comment: Oh, I get it now..
Thank u all :)